# Passing a value from html to javascript function on click?

Tags: javascript

Basically, on clicking any image on a html page I want the id associated to be passed to a function.
This is what I have tried. It seems I am making a minor mistake here as I am getting the **first** id passed no matter what image I click from the array. I tried $(this).attr("id") as well, but did not work.

```
            for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length-1;i++){
                var rows = '';
                var bg_img = jsonObj[i].img;
                var bg_img = decodeURIComponent(bg_img);                    
                rows = "<img id='" + jsonObj[i].source_id + "' src='" + bg_img + "'/>";                 
                document.getElementsByClassName('subscription')[i].innerHTML = rows;
            }                           

            $("body").delegate(".subscription", "click", function() {
                //  var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    alert("Welcome Test " + $('img').attr("id"));
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("img").click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$('img')` selector is not confined to any specific area, so it will give you the first image on the entire page.

Try `$('img',this)` instead.